# Ubuntu not starting after remove usb drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I'd like to mount on start up an usb drive, so I added on /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda1 /folder auto noatime 0 0
```

The problem is, if I remove the usb drive and reboot the system or change the drive to another one ubuntu server will not be avaliable, I cannot ssh using putty or open any service from it. It seems like it won't boot if I remove the drive or change it to another one.

Anybody knows what happens? I'd like to mount a drive at start up, but if it is not found just ignore it and continue up to other services.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326791/108618

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks, I added nofail option, I think it will work from now on.